# not able to prove a trig identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For the identity,

$$\dfrac{\cos A}{1 - \tan A} + \dfrac{\sin A}{1 - \cot A}=\sin A + \cos A$$

What I have been able to perform,
$$
\dfrac{\cos A}{\dfrac{\cos A}{\cos A}-\dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A}} + \dfrac{\sin A}{\dfrac{\sin A}{\sin A} - \dfrac{\cos A}{\sin A}}$$

$$
\dfrac{\cos^2 A}{\cos A - \sin A} + \dfrac{\sin^2 A}{\sin A - \cos A}
$$
I am unable to prove this identity

Comment: It's very hard and cumbersome to read what you wrote. Please do use MathJaX to write mathematics in this site. The easy directions to do so are somewhere out there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think it's highly likely based on OP's level that they don't know how to use MathJax and learning how for one question is probably more effort than it's worth.  You could try to edit the question yourself or, if you don't want to, I will after I am done posting my answer.

Comment: @user46944 Some times I edit, some times I don't. It is just that if the OP wants his post read he must be sure to write in a readable fashion. I, for one, wouldn't even try to read this: too messy for me.

Comment: @DonAntonio You're entitled to your perfectly reasonable opinion.  I try to help users as much as I can on this site, even if it means recognizing their limitations in type setting their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$${c^2\over c-s}+{s^2\over s-c}={s^2-c^2\over s-c}$$

Now factor the numerator.  (In other words, what you did was correct, you just have to keep going.)

Comment: Do you reach this by expansion

Comment: actually I am struggling with the expansion from the lhs to rhs

Comment: @user369475, the two fractions on the LHS have essentially the same denominator, just with opposite signs.  I.e, $c-s=-(s-c)$.

Comment: I am unable to take reduce the expression form the lhs to the rhs

Comment: Ah I get it thank you

Comment: @user369475, oh good.  (We might do well to delete all these comments, since they are superfluous now.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we want to verify that $$\frac{\cos{A}}{1 - \tan{A}} + \frac{\sin{A}}{1 - \cot{A}} = \sin{A} + \cos{A}.$$

Staring with the left hand side, we have (based on what you've already done):

\begin{split} \frac{\cos{A}}{1 - \tan{A}} + \frac{\sin{A}}{1 - \cot{A}} &= \frac{\cos{A}}{\left(\frac{\cos{A} - \sin{A}}{\cos{A}}\right)} + \frac{\sin{A}}{\left(\frac{\sin{A} - \cos{A}}{\sin{A}}\right)} \\ &= \frac{\cos^{2}{A}}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} + \frac{\sin^{2}{A}}{\sin{A}-\cos{A}}  \end{split}

where we got the last step by inverting and multiplying the fractions in the denominators. Now, it should be clear to you that $\sin{A}- \cos{A}= -(\cos{A} - \sin{A})$ so we can make the denominators of the two fractions the same by pulling out a minus sign from the second denominator, to get:

\begin{split} \frac{\cos^{2}{A}}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} + \frac{\sin^{2}{A}}{\sin{A}-\cos{A}} &= \frac{\cos^{2}{A}}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} - \frac{\sin^{2}{A}}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} \\ &= \frac{\cos^{2}{A} - \sin^{2}(A)}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}}  \end{split}

and recognizing the numerator of that last fraction is the difference of squares! So it factors into $(\cos{A} - \sin{A})(\cos{A} + \sin{A})$, giving us:

\begin{split}\frac{\cos^{2}{A} - \sin^{2}(A)}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} &= \frac{(\cos{A} - \sin{A})(\cos{A} + \sin{A})}{\cos{A}-\sin{A}} \\ &= \cos{A} + \sin{A} \end{split}

where we cancelled the common factor of $(\cos{A} - \sin{A})$ from the numerator and denominator in the last step.